# WPF event on disabled window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there any possibility to handle an event on a disabled WPF window? The main window is disabled by `.ShowDialog()` from other windows. In my application there is only one window enabled at a time and I want to improve the usability. If the user clicks on the wrong (disabled) main window the application should auto focus to the enabled window.

I know that disabled means that the window does not respond to any event, but is there a solution like a global event handler or some special WPF event?

I tried a `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event but that did not work.

```cs
// event called from some special/ global event on disabled window
private void Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(App.Current.Windows.Count > 1)
    {
       foreach(Window w in App.Current.Windows)
       {
           if(w.IsEnabled) 
           {
               w.Focus();
               break;
           }
       }          
    }
}
```

Thanks for your ideas/solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ShowDialog` means you want to make window being showed **modal**, which disables other windows.

Switch this method to `Show` and you'll be able to use other windows as well.

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint but as a requirement I've to ensure that the main window is freezed when another window is opened and I've found a solution: Instead of freezing the window with `.ShowDialog()` I've freezed all controls when a new window is opened with `.Show()`.

```cs
private void DisableAllControls()
{
    // parallel execution cause of many elements
    Parallel.For(0, VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this), index =>
    {
        (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, index)
        as UIElement).IsEnabled = false;
    });
}
```

I also added a `MouseDownEvent` to get focus an the new window if the user clicks on the "freezed" main window. (There will be only one additional window open at the same time).

```cs
private void FocusLastOpen_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (App.Current.Windows.Count > 1)
    {
        foreach (Window w in App.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (w.IsEnabled && w.GetType() != typeof(MainWindow))
            {
                w.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To reactivate the elements of the main window when the other window has closed I've written a static method which will be executed on the `ClosingEvent`.

```cs
public static void EnableAllControls()
{
    MainWindow obj = null;
    foreach(Window w in App.Current.Windows)
    {
        if(w.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
        {
            obj = w as MainWindow;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(obj == null) return;
    Parallel.For(0, VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj), index =>
    {
        (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, index)
        as UIElement).IsEnabled = true;
    });
}
```